# How does the the Objective-C import process work?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

So I have a class called HUDLayer.h and HUDLayer.m and inside .m, I'm running the following:

```
#import "HUDLayer.h"
#import "Gamescene.h"
#import "GameplayLayer.h"
#import "Bear.h"
[GameScene sharedGamePlayLayer].bear.stamina;
```

My question is.. why do I need to import GameplayLayer.h and bear.h? (If I don't, I lead to forward class declaration errors)

My GameScene.h has already imported those 2. Because of that, I thought I wouldn't have to import it again. Unless I have the wrong idea of how importing works.

EDIT: Realized my mistake. I've been using @class in my headers but I guess in the case where I have references outside of that same header file that refers to a @class, I have to replace that @class with an import. (Sorry guys, still learning the objective-c stuff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to import these files again, as soon as `GameplayLayer.h` and `Bear.h` are imported in `Gamescene.h` (i.e. public interface file of a class) — and not in private `Gamescene.m`, as you probably do it now.

Comment: Yes but prefer to use @class and import in the implementation rather than the header. This prevents cyclic imports, and should also speed up compilation.

Comment: Really? Some other posts I viewed just suggest that I just use @class in the header since we're not going to be accessing those objects in the header.